# Capistrano deploy failed after moving to bitbucket.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bitbucket

It is for rails application. Used to be on github and was moving to bitbucket.org. Did the following before `cap deploy`:

```
cap deploy:cleanup -s keep_releases=0
```

Deleted /shared/cached-copy/ completely. The following error is from `cap deploy`:

```
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/byop/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/byop/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 6da8873d384fa53b19b20646593342109d3b58d6 && git
 clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@bitbucket.org:username/byop.git /var/www/byop/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/byop/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 6da8873d384fa53b19b20646593342109d3b58d6; fi'"
on x.x.x.x
```

Also tried both public or private repo on bitbucket.org and the error is the same. What could cause the problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no real error shown, I can only guess.

You have to set up a deployment key in bitbucket for the user on your server. If this is not set up, git commands won't work.

I do also deploy with capistrano to a virtual server using bitbucket and it works fine.
Maybe check the lines following your output if there are more hints.